# Issue with magento udropship & languages / storeviews

Tags: magento

So my problem regarding `MAGENTO` languages and view stores.

I have a website with one language Spanish. I got an extention installed for Vendors which can come and add products and so. My issue is, that I want my vendors portal to be in English and the vendor portal is take the language from the default store in my system which is Spanish.
I added another store ENGLISH one, but when I change my default store to the english on I get my main website in English.

Im strugeling with it, I dont know how do fix that issue. I was thinking maybe I can somehow  change the language in the vendors portal specificly from code? Or maybe you got other solution.

my extention is `Udropship` for refrences.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set English as default language and Spanish as language for your default website/storeview. Go to System/Configuration. Look into the top left corner, thre is select where you can switch config scope. If you set this so then admin panel will be displayed in English whilst frontend will be still displayed in Spanish.

Comment: The thing is that the udropship vendor portal main language , taken from the view store.. so if the website will be spanish the vendor portal aswell.
Im trying to find a way to split them somwhoe